# Conditional render + add some extra code in React

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I'm aware of some of the conditional rendering methods for React components. Some of them can be found [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e/).

Using ternary operatiors, if...elses.... But I want to know if theres a way to render a component based on a condition and **perform some calculations before rendering**.

A normal conditional render will look like this:

```
<>
   {myCondition && (<MyComponent /)}
</>
```

But what I need to know if it's possible to do, is something like this

```
<>
   {myCondition && 
       const myVars = 'Some random vars I need'; // try to gather some info before rendering the component
       return <MyComponent vars={myVars} />
    }
</>
```

Is there a way to perform this operation before rendering?

Comment: Okay so you'll need to gather all relevant data before rendering, you can use a state variable for it, which can help you render different views when the value changes

Comment: True... Gonna try and see if it covers my needs. Thanks @SampurnG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use useState, useEffect hooks and some if operators like this:

```
const [myVars, SetMyVars] = useState("")
const [myCondition, SetMyCondition] = useState(false)
    
useEffect(() => {
    if(myCondition) {
      SetMyVars("something")
    }
},[myCondition])
    
    return (
       {myCondition && <MyComponent vars={myVars} /> }
    )
```

and then you can add some code to change your condition and etc.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to render content conditionally is by defining a helper function and calling it right away.

```
import React from 'react'

const renderContent = ()=>{
    // add some logic here
    // all sort of things you can imagine
    // include if statements containing return statements
}

function tryThis() {
  return (
    <div>{renderContent()}</div>
  )
}

export default tryThis
```